# AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'appdirs'

Tags: python, module, pkg-resources

I am getting following error, could not find any solution, can anyone assist in this?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_10658/1029138787.py in <module>
      2 import datetime
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from ovationpyme.ovation_prime import FluxEstimator,AverageEnergyEstimator,BinCorrector
      5 from ovationpyme.ovation_utilities import calc_avg_solarwind
      6 from ovationpyme.ovation_plotting import latlt2polar,polar2dial,pcolor_flux

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ovationpyme-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/ovationpyme/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import ovation_prime
      2 from . import ovation_utilities
      3 from . import ovation_plotting

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ovationpyme-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/ovationpyme/ovation_prime.py in <module>
     10 from scipy import interpolate
     11 
---> 12 from ovationpyme import ovation_utilities
     13 
     14 from ovationpyme.ovation_utilities import robinson_auroral_conductance

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ovationpyme-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/ovationpyme/ovation_utilities.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from geospacepy import special_datetime, sun
---> 11 from nasaomnireader.omnireader import omni_interval
     12 from logbook import Logger
     13 log = Logger('OvationPyme.ovation_utilites')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nasaomnireader-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/nasaomnireader/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # (C) 2020 University of Colorado AES-CCAR-SEDA (Space Environment Data Analysis) Group
      2 # Written by Liam M. Kilcommons
----> 3 from nasaomnireader.default_config import config

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nasaomnireader-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/nasaomnireader/default_config.py in <module>
      6 src_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
      7 
----> 8 appdirs = pkg_resources.appdirs.AppDirs('nasaomnireader','cuseda')
      9 
     10 data_dir = appdirs.user_data_dir #~/.local/share/AMGeO on Ubuntu

AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'appdirs'
```

I tried to run following code and got the above error:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ovationpyme.ovation_prim`e import FluxEstimator,AverageEnergyEstimator,BinCorrector
from ovationpyme.ovation_utilities import calc_avg_solarwind
from ovationpyme.ovation_plotting import latlt2polar,polar2dial,pcolor_flux
from geospacepy.spherical_geometry import grid_surface_integral
import ipywidgets
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import partial
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the Ovation Pyme package. The `nasaomnireader` package config file (during setup) uses `pkg_resources` to determine installation directory, and `pkg_resources` has since changed/been deprecated. I installed the `appdirs` package and modified `default_config.py` in the nasaomnireader directory to use AppDirs in the `appdirs` package instead of in `pkg_resources`. Then I reinstalled `nasaomnireader`.

To install appdir

```
pip install appdir
```

modified version of default_config.py in nasaomnireader

```
import pkg_resources,os,appdirs

#Determine where this module's source file is located
src_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

appdirs = appdirs.AppDirs('nasaomnireader','cuseda')

data_dir = appdirs.user_data_dir #~/.local/share/AMGeO on Ubuntu

print('Solar wind data files will be saved to {}'.format(data_dir))
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    print('Created {}'.format(data_dir))
    os.makedirs(data_dir)

config = {
    'omnireader' : {
        'local_cdf_dir':data_dir
    }
}
```

and then reinstall nasaomnireader.